# Count lines in textarea including automatic line breaks

Tags: php, html, forms, validation, textarea

I have a textarea

```
<textarea id="text" name="text" rows="6"></textarea>

<style>
    #text { width: 30%; }
</style>
```

When submitting the form, I need to check if the input exceeded 6 rows. I have a JS code, which checks for scrollbar (scrollbar present = more than 6 lines = invalid input) which works perfectly. The tricky part is, how can validate the input with PHP in case of disabled JS?

I tried something like this

```
public function overflowValidator($input, $maxLines, $cols) {
    $linebreakCount = substr_count($input, "\n");
    $overflow1 = ($linebreakCount <= $maxLines);
    $overflow2 = (ceil(strlen($input) / $cols) <= $maxLines);
    return $overflow1 && $overflow2;
}
```

The biggest problem is that the width of the textarea is dynamic (responsive design) so I can't easily tell how many letters fit into one line. I'm afraid this can't be solved but maybe there is a solution I'm not aware of...

Comment: Why don't you count the count the number of characters in the string instead? I don't see the purpose in counting lines...

Comment: int strlen ( string $string )

Comment: When I later display it on a different page, the container must have exactly same size as the textarea so it looks the same in both of them (and I need to limit the size of it by limitting the number of lines). That's why...

Comment: Still, calculating the number of lines to create an identical textarea doesn't make a lot of sense to me. There is a reason why character count functions are standard in either PHP or Javascript, and not line count. I'd just create another text area with identical dimensions and limit the number of characters...

Answer (score 2):

**Count total lines :-**

```
$lines = preg_split('/\n|\r/',$str);
$Total_lines = count($lines); 
echo $Total_lines;
```

Answer (score 1):

It might be a better idea to count the total amount of characters instead of lines but here is the code which allows you to do that :

```
    preg_match_all("/(\n)/", $_POST['text'], $matches);
    $total_lines = count($matches[0]) + 1;
```